# "buffer is not visiting file" when trying to tail "elfeed-log"

Tags: auto-revert-mode, elfeed

When I turn on auto revert tail mode on a *elfeed-log* buffer I get
error "buffer is not visiting file" in the mini buffer.

So now what?

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the problem with a minimal `elfeed` setup?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know elfeed-log, but my crystal ball suggests, in order:

1. just put the cursor at the very end of the buffer, and the window keep scrolling to keep the end of the buffer visible.
2. if that doesn't work, set `window-point-insertion-type` to `t` in the elfeed-log buffer and try step 1 again.
3. if neither works, send your problem to the maintainer of the elfeed-log code because it likely needs changes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says the *elfeed-log* buffer is not visting a file but it's automatically updated by elfeed itself

Comment: but I need to tail it, see the lower end dynamically

Comment: You should add this information in the original question, now it's not immediately evident that you are interested in the automatic scrolling

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and dirty solution, this can be considered.

```
(add-hook 'after-change-functions
          (lambda (_b _e _len)
            (let ((my-window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer) t)))
              (set-window-point my-window (point)))))
          nil t)
```

Issued within the buffer.